# sizeof in D language

Tags: size, d, sizeof

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    write(a.sizeof);
}
```

In following code sizeof of static array is equals to 8 byte. I use x86 Windows 8, so pointer is equals to 4 byte.
Why I get 8 byte size of array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `int[]` is a dynamic array, not a pointer. Arrays in D are not pointers. What they are is essentially

```
struct(T)
{
    T* ptr;
    size_t length;
}
```

So, if you want the underlying pointer, you need to use the array's `ptr` member, though that's usually only needed when interacting with C/C++ code (since dynamic arrays in C/C++ *are* just pointers). However, the `length` member is used all the time and helps make arrays in D far more powerful and pleasant to work with than arrays in C/C++ are. If you want to know more about arrays in D, then you should read [this article](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html). It goes into a fair bit of detail about them, and I would consider it a must-read for all D programmers.

Regardless, what `sizeof` is giving you is the size of `ptr` and `length` together, which would be `8` on 32-bit systems, and `16` on 64-bit systems.

Comment: While I don't think this is required of the standard, it is interesting to point out in the D ABI right now, a dynamic array actually puts the length first in memory, then the pointer. Doesn't change the meat of what you said though.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Technically, I don't think that there _is_ an official ABI for dynamic arrays. As I understand it, they don't even technically have to be implemented with `ptr` and `length`. They could be implemented as `begin` and `end` pointers so long as the properties `ptr` and `length` exist (though they'd be property functions in that case). But realistically, at this point, they're going to be implemented with `ptr` and `length` members. It might be worth actually specifying that (and their order) in the spec, but I don't know what the tradeoffs are for specifying it or not specifying it.

Answer (score 7):

A dynamic array (what you have) is behind the scenes actually a struct with a pointer and a `size_t` length both being 4 on your CPU.

This allows D to carry along the length of the array to avoid out of bounds reading and writing (if you have the check enabled) and a `O(1)` slice operation.